# Why does clicking a link go to the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, jquery-events

This may sound a weird question,
I have a page which has a link:

```
<a href="#" class="emails" > Email to Friends </a>
```

Now I have an event attach to the anchor tag so that on click the given div toggle it state.

The Javascript Code look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".emails").bind("click",function() {
       $("div#container").toggle
   })
})
```

Now the above code and all of it works fine,
but here the big deal,
when I click the given link the **my focus of the page move to top** of the page,
and I have to scroll all the way down to see the change.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does this because the `href="#"` is an empty anchor.  Anchors are used for linking to specific spots within a page.  An empty anchor results in the page going back to the top.

To fix this in your javascript, you need to prevent the click event from [propagating or  "bubbling"](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) up the DOM.  You can do this by returning false from your click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".emails").bind("click",function() {
       $("div#container").toggle();
       return false; // prevent propagation
   })
});
```

You can also make the event available in the bind's click handler function by using an argument, usually named `e`.  Having access to the event allows you to call methods on it such as `.preventDefault()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".emails").bind("click", function(event) {
       $("div#container").toggle();
       event.preventDefault(); // this can also go at the start of the method if you prefer
   })
});
```

Comment: Another solution, similar to above: 
`$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".emails").bind("click",function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default action of link, no need for return false
       $("div#container").toggle();
       
   });
});`

Answer (score 1):

This will solve all cases where anchor is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        $('[href = #]');
        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: This a the simple solution for an empty anchor to avoid going to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the `href='#'` in the `a`. Just remove this tag. But then it's technically not a link any more, so the cursor will default to a text-selector when over it. You can override this using `cursor:pointer` in your CSS. See the left menu [on this website](http://www.artarium.in) for reference.

Comment: The issue with a CSS hyperlink lookalike is that on clicking it, the text gets selected as well as triggering JS. Makes it look ugly.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because in the site I linked that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Use a simpler case. There's a whole lot of CSS and all going on there: http://jsbin.com/ihehef/2 . Here, I've done the bare minimum that you suggested: Have a link, cauterize the `href`, CSS it to look like a link; give it a `cursor`. The link prints "did something". That's it. Watch how the link gets selected on a double-click. Keep clicking, the whole line gets selected. Not normal link behaviour, even for a `#` link.

Comment: The same effect happens to me on that site as well. (I'm using chrome) Doubleclick the galleries link. Multiple-click it. It ends up selecting part of the page. Not good, especially if there are other click-sensitive things o the page. Deselecting it requires a click. It gets annoying on a webapp when someone uses this trick, as deselecting it requires a click in that area, which may lead to another event being triggered. So it's bad practice.

Comment: @Manishearth, +1 and thanks. This knowledge helped me out with my own website. But a `#` is appended to the address bar if we do this. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Never mind, @Manishearth. `href="javascript:void(0)"` takes care of that, like your answer says. So I'll +1 that too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="emails" > Email to Friends </a>
```

Or, using jQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".emails").attr("href","javascript:void(0)");
})
```

Void(0) returns a.. well.. it doesn't return anything. The browser knows how to go to nothing (i.e., what would happen if you did `href=""`), and to `#` (`#` is the top of the page), but not how to go to a void "value".

Whenever you put a `javascript:` in an attribute, the attribute's value gets set to the return value of the code inside. The code is called the first time the attribute is accessed.

But, `void(0)` returns nothing. Not even `""`. The browser takes this to meant that the link is not a link at all.

Comment: I wouldn't use this solution. What if you have a hundred links on a page? You don't want to add javascript to each href attribute and also you want to keep logic and structure separate.

Comment: voted down for inline javascript when the OP is already using JQuery.